# Best way to block XSS injection having decode and getParameter

Tags: java, security, xss, decode, getparameter

I have a lot of this type of old code in my Liferay app :

```
String code = request.getParameter("code");
```

It seems that in Liferay there is a "HtmlUtil.escape" function, so I assume I can use it like :

```
String code = HtmlUtil.escapeAttribute(request.getParameter("code"));
```

Is this the safest way to do it ?

I also have another simple java project :

```
public void buildParams(String[] items, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    typeRequest = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter(ReportUtil.PARAMETER_REQUEST_TYPE));
    countEx = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter(ReportUtil.PARAMETER_COUNT));

    Map<String, String> parametres = ReportGenerator.decodeMap(request.getParameter("parameters"), String.class);
    ...
```

What is the classic way to block injection without the Liferay "HtmlUtil.escape" function here ?

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlUtil.escape` allows you to escape certain text so that it is safe to use in an HTML context.

As a drop in replacement you can use the different methods provided by the Apache `commons-text` library [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) class, especially the `escapeXml**` ones.

Please, in any way, consider read the [documentation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) created by OWASP about Cross Site Scripting prevention.

It provides great insights about the different related types of attacks involved in the term, and how you can prevent or mitigate everyone of them.

The documentation provides references to several related libraries like the [OWASP Java Encoder project](https://owasp.org/www-project-java-encoder/) and [OWASP Java Html Sanitizer](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer).

The first project gives you [some examples](https://owasp.org/www-project-java-encoder/#div-use) for handling untrusted content in different scenarios.

The second one allows you for a more structured HTML processing based on user defined policies. Please, consider review the different [examples](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/tree/main/src/main/java/org/owasp/html/examples) provided in the Github repository.

If you require a full fledged prevention framework, you can use in your application the artifacts provided for [ESAPI](https://owasp.org/www-project-enterprise-security-api/) project, from OWASP as well.

There is nothing wrong with escaping the information you are receiving with classes like `HtmtUtil` in your server side code but, as you can see in the different examples provided, in order to prevent XSS related attacks, it is typical to perform some kind of encoding/escaping when *outputting* the HTML code fragment instead, when you are *providing the information to your client*: the important thing is to prevent that somebody may, for example, introduce a terminal `</textarea>` tag that terminates a `textarea` and then a `<script>...</script>` block with some malicious code next:

```html
</textarea><script>alert('hello')</script>
```

The kind of server side processing you are describing is more frequently used when you want to prevent other types of code injection. Please, consider read [this other documentation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) again from the OWASP website, I think it could be useful.

Comment: @user2178964 Were you able to review any of the proposed solutions? I updated the answer with some examples references and clarifications.  I hope they help.